# Why getting blank output when running "/bin/sh" with "-c" option

Tags: bash, sh

I am running `/bin/sh` with `-c` option as below but getting a blank output:

```
[root@dockerhost dproj]# /bin/sh -c echo helloworld
[root@dockerhost dproj]#
```

Why the above command is not printing `helloworld?`

I have tried to read the `man page` but not able to understand anything.

From `man sh`:

```
   -c        Read  commands  from the command_string operand. 
             Set the value of special parameter 0 
             (see Section 2.5.2, Special Parameters) from the
             value of the command_name operand and the positional
             parameters ($1, $2, and so on) in sequence from the 
             remaining argument  operands.
             No commands shall be read from the standard input.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/bin/sh -c echo helloworld` runs the command `echo`, which prints a blank line. You meant to type:

```bash
/bin/sh -c "echo helloworld"
```

which runs the command `echo helloworld`.

The `-c` option to `sh` causes the first non-option argument to be treated as a string of commands to run in a new shell. The remaining arguments are used to fill in the that shell's numbered arguments, starting with `$0` (the "name" under which the shell process is running.) These arguments are not automatically parsed to any utility executed by that shell.

So if you invoke `sh` with `/bin/sh -c echo helloworld`:

- the input passed to the shell interpreter `sh` is simply `echo`
- `helloworld` becomes `$0` in the `sh` session.

Normally, `$0` in a shell invocation should be the name of the shell; that's what it will be set to by default:

```
bash$ /bin/sh
$ echo $0
/bin/sh
$ exit
bash$ echo $0
bash
```

Since the command given to the shell by `-c` is interpreted as though it were input to the shell itself, you can use `$n` in the command in order to refer to the extra arguments to the shell interpreter. If you want to do that, you need to remember to single-quote the `-c` option argument so that it's contents are not interpreted by the outer shell. Perhaps studying the following will help:

```
bash$ /bin/sh -c 'echo $0' fakename   # Correctly single-quoted
fakename
bash$ /bin/sh -c "echo $0" fakename   # Here, $0 is expanded by the outer shell
bash
bash$ /bin/sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh arg1 arg2 arg3  # $0 is not part of $@
arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Sure thanks. can you please help me understand the behaviour of `/bin/sh -c`?

Comment: @meallhour: I tried, but your best bet is to read through `man sh` or some other guide to shell scripting.